# bind() works for ipv6 wireless adapter interface but not for ipv6 ethernet (error 10049)

Tags: bind, ip-address, ipv6, unicast, windows-socket-api

**Background**

At the beginning of my program I build a linked list of adapter interface addresses using [GetAdaptersAddresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses). Later, after creating an `ipv6 slaac` address, calling `Socket()`, `Bind()` and `Listen()` all succeed where the `IfType` is Wireless, that is, `IfType` 71 (`IF_TYPE_IEEE80211`). My filter parameters are `family` and `ifType`. I test by connecting and disconnecting the ethernet cable. For each case my software finds the active interface with said parameters: connected it finds ethernet first, disconnected it doesn't find ethernet, then looks further for a wireless interface. See SO [Unable to GetUnicastIpAddressEntry after CreateUnicastIpAddressEntry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702391/unable-to-getunicastipaddressentry-after-createunicastipaddressentry) for relevant code snippets.

**Problem**

However, if the interface's `IfType` is 6 (`IF_TYPE_ETHERNET_CSMACD`), `Socket()` succeeds, but `Bind()` and of course `Listen()` then fails.

**Question**

Are there any other factors or interface parameters I have left out that can determine the outcome?

**Attempt1**

Cycle through all ipv6 interfaces just to empirically determine if any would succeed. None did on two machines.

**Attempt2**

Looked for `scope id` and append that to address, however, I didn't see the `scope id` parameter in the interface linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attempt3**

`Bind()` will fail to enter the ip address into the internal table if `ipRow.DadState` is not set to `IpDadStatePreferred` after the call to [InitializeUnicastIpAddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-initializeunicastipaddressentry) and before the call to [CreateUnicastIpAddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/drivers/ff546227%28v%3Dvs.85%29):

```
ipRow.DadState = IpDadStatePreferred; // RT:191204: beginning with windows 10, this results in 'preferred' instead of 'tentative'
```

This results in a binding to a `preferred` socket upon which `Listen()` can be successfully called.

Here are the incorrect doc snippets in `CreateUnicastIpAddressEntry`:

> If the value of the DadState member returns with some value other than
>   IpDadStatePreferred or IpDadStateTentative, duplicate address
>   detection has failed and the IP address is not usable.

If the returned `DadState` is `IpDadStateTentative`, the address is not useable either.

Also, there is this:

> The `DadState`, `ScopeId`, and `CreationTimeStamp` members of the
>   `MIB_UNICASTIPADDRESS_ROW` structure that the Row parameter points to
>   are ignored when the `CreateUnicastIpAddressEntry` function is called.

`DadState` is not ignored, and as stated before will result in a non-preferred, non-useable address if not set to preferred.